# RSA/ECB/NoPadding decryption returning null characters

Tags: java, rsa

I am encrypting a string using RSA algorithm and encryption and decryption  logic is

```
public class RsaEncrypt {

private static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filePath = "/home/Desktop/abc.jks";
    char[] password = "changeit".toCharArray();
    String alias = "123";
    KeyStore ks = null;

    try {

        //loading the keystore
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        InputStream readStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        ks.load(readStream, password);
        Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate(alias);

        PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, password);

        RsaEncrypt e = new RsaEncrypt();
        String result = e.encrypt("abvhdh", publicKey);
        String decryptResult = e.decrypt(result.getBytes(), privateKey);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


//Encryption of a string

public String encrypt(String text,PublicKey publicKey) {

    String retVal = null;
    byte[] cipherText = null;

    try {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
         cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());

        cipherText = Base64.getEncoder().encode(cipherText);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    }
    return new String(cipherText) ;
}




// Decryption of a string
    private String decrypt(byte[] text, PrivateKey privatekey) {
        byte[] dectyptedText = null;

        try {
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privatekey);
            dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(text));

            } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return new String(dectyptedText);
    }
```

The Result is fine.But if i encrypt same string one more time i am getting different encryption value.

For that i am using "RSA/ECB/NoPadding" cipher instead of "RSA",then If i encrypt one string many times i am getting same encryption value.
But when i decrypt,The reuslt string contains some null characters

Example
**input** : abcd                                                                                                                                   **output** : abcd \u0000 \u0000 \u0000  \u0000....

How can i resolve this problem and what is the best way to get same encryption value if we encrypt multiple times?????

Answer (score 2):

> The Result is fine.But if i encrypt same string one more time i am getting different encryption value.

That is correct and it is even required property of the RSA encryption. By default PKCS1.5 padding is used (RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding) which contains some random bytes. Safer option is `RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING` mode which is even more random.

> For that i am using "RSA/ECB/NoPadding" cipher instead of "RSA",then If i encrypt one string many times i am getting same encryption value. But when i decrypt,The reuslt string contains some null characters

Using RSA without padding (`NoPadding`) is very unsafe (it is called [textbook RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/definition-of-textbook-rsa)).

Padding extends the original encrypted value to full space length (e.g. 2048 bits) and then the RSA magic (exponentiation) will be executed. Using the NoPadding parameter you are telling the crypto library that you will do the padding yourself. In that case you are expected to remove the padding after decryption (in your case zero padding)

I hope you are doing that for learning / academic purposes, not some real security project. You may have a look at my [blog about encryption](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/) to get some examples.

btw: you should not use RSA to encrypt the plaintext itself. Rather use symmetric encryption to encrypt the plaintext and then RSA to encrypt the symmetric encryption key.

Comment: Thank you for your reposnse.. Is there any way to get same encrypted value using "RSA" algorithm???

Comment: @anth why would you want the same value? One option is using own static padding (like your `NoPadding`), but that lowers security of your solution. Random padding is necessary for RSA to be secure.  Wrongly implemented padding 
could even reveal your private key.

Comment: Actually i am generating a random value for a number and storing both random value and number(encrypted value) in database.    If try to genearate random value for already existing encrypted value then i will get exception. i need to check wheteher the encrypted value is present in database or not .To check this condition i need to get same value for one number(multiple times encryption)

Comment: @anth that's not what (rsa) encryption is intended for. If you want to compare values, hash (or hmac) may suit you better.